# can do worse than . .

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

Does it make sense literally to say the following?

> You can do worse than ask John for advice.

What does "can" mean here?

I know it's used to make a suggestion, but I want to know if the meaning can be deduced from the meaning of its parts.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is this from? What is the context?

Comment: "You can do worse than actually make your own individual list here."

Comment: https://books.google.com./books?id=-oYq9IyXz60C&pg=PA15&dq="can+do+worse+than"&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidk9m_vqbpAhXcy4sBHefeCCsQ6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q="can%20do%20worse%20than"&f=false

Comment: You can do X; it is possible for you to do X; it is possible for you to do worse than X; there are worse choices than X; X is a better choice than some other possible choices.

Comment: Sometimes you will see 'you _could_ do worse than...'

Comment: I find "can do worse than ..." hard to make sense of literally, because "You can V" can be used to make a suggestion. "You can call John" could be paraphrased as "What you should do is call John." If so, "you can do worse than call John" would be literally understood as "What you should do is do something worse than call John."

Comment: _You can do worse_ seems very odd to me. I think it's a mistake for _you could do worse than_ (meaning that there are several possibilities and this is one of the better ones).

Comment: @KateBunting - lots of examples on the web - a couple at random -  “If you want to make characters sound insane, you can do worse than infect their speech with adverbs.” (a blog) and "Should a democracy have a King Wills and Queen Kate? You can do worse" (Timothy Garton Ash, the Guardian)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey There are a few words used to indicate possibility. I'm wondering whether the "can" in "You can do worse than V" is used atypically.
In affirmative sentences, "can" seems to indicate a tendency or habit, not tied to a one-time occasion. "He can be at home" seems an incorrect version of "He could/may/might be at home," whereas "It can get really cold in the winter there" seems fine. Is the "can" in "You can do worse than ask John for help" an unusual word choice for this reason?

Comment: I don't agree that 'can' is particularly unusual in 'you can do worse...'. I have seen 'you _might_ do worse than...' used also.

Comment: "Might" makes better sense than "can," We could say "he might be at home now," but not "he can be at home now."